# hyper ledgerfabric Or Substrate

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, substrate

I want to learn how to build blockchain networks, but I was a little confused as to which one to choose between Hyper Ledger Fabric and Substrate.
Please guide me if anyone knows which of the two has a better future and more advantages.use between choices.

another question I want to know is can I Use the `Rust` in Hyper Ledger Fabric?

Comment: Can you clarify what your goals are with the project you would like to build?

Comment: Also, the second part of you question is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking Substrate provides an extreme degree of flexibility and allows you to optionally use battle tested modules built by blockchain experts.

Many users take advantage of the FRAME framework, which is designed to work with substrate and provide the scaffolding for deeply interconnected modules, consensus, mempool logic, and block execution.

A big advantage is that with Substrate you can update the core block validation logic (aka. Runtime or State Transition Function) seamlessly and securely by broadcasting the new logic as a wasm blob in a block.

Another major advantage is that Substrate chains can be developed as a stand alone chain, and then with very little effort they can then later become a parachain or parathread, reaping the benefits of ultra secure cross chain message passing and state transition validation.

Further, there are many pre-built Substrate modules (pallets) from different open source projects, including ORML, Substrate's own FRAME, and many more.

Wether you just want to build a PoC for a school project, launch a new standalone chain, or build something for the polkadot ecosystem Substrate is a great place to start as you can start with the node template to be up an running and minutes and then as you develop and deeply customize your project you can seamlessly upgrade your live networks.

There are many other benefits to Substrate. Here are few resources I recommend to get started:

- Tutorial to create you first substrate chain: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/create-your-first-substrate-chain/
- Overview of Substrate: https://docs.substrate.io/v3/getting-started/overview/
- Architecture of a node built with Substrate: https://docs.substrate.io/v3/getting-started/architecture/
- And finally I recommend reading the concepts section of the developer docs, starting with the runtime docs: https://docs.substrate.io/v3/concepts/runtime/

Ultimately Substrate gives you the flexibility to make almost any design, and in areas your project doesn't have a strict opinion you can use the battle tested components built by the substrate community.